# cannot sign my android app apk with google retrieved key

Tags: java, android, jks

I lost my google play upload key, google sent me a new one, but i can't get android studio to accept it. There seems to be very little documentation on this.
Here is what i have done.

Downloaded the .der file from my google console
ran keytool.exe

I have tried generated jks files using keytool e.g.

c:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_121\bin>keytool -importcert -file "upload_cert.der" -keystore newUntrustedUploadWithPassword.jks -alias "untrustedKey" -keypass bandits

however i get an error failed in android studio: trusted certificate entries are not password-protect
however i have to provide a password to sign the APK
and if i choose not to trust the certificate keytool doesn't add it/generate it.

So what am i missing
Please advise. 
Many thanks